# Table data in a drop down based on column name

Tags: angular5

I have a mock data like this :

```
export const CHARACTERS: any[] =
[
  {
    name: 'Earl of Lemongrab',
    age: 'Unknown',
    species: 'Lemon Candy',
    occupation: 'Earl, Heir to the Candy Kingdom Throne'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bonnibel Bubblegum',
    age: '19',
    species: 'Gum Person',
    occupation: 'Returned Ruler of the Candy Kingdom'
  },
  {
    name: 'Phoebe',
    age: '16',
    species: 'Flame Person',
    occupation: 'Ruler of the Fire Kingdom'
  }
```

I have taken this data and displaying it on a table. Now i want to display all this data inside a drop down based on column names.

I am using below code but its not displaying properly ;

```
  <div class = "two">
   <select [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="char[column]" placeholder="select">
     <option 
       *ngFor="let char of characters"
          *ngFor="let column of columns"
       [ngValue]="char[column]">{{char[column]}}</option>  
   </select>
  </div>
```

I have also tried below code but it gives me an error saying that name is not a know property of the column. Although my column has four strings like ["name" , "age" , "species" , "gender"]

```
  <div class = "two">
   <select [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="column" placeholder="select">
    <option 
     *ngFor="let column of columns"
     value="column.name">{{column.name}}</option>  
   </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class = "two">
   <select [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="char[column]" placeholder="select">
     <option 
          *ngFor="column of columns"
       Value="char[column.name]">{{char[column.name]}}</option>  
   </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't have access to char as i am using only one for loop on columns